# SSLError when running python script on Windows Server

Tags: ssl, proxy, python, squid, windows-server-2019

I am trying to run a python script on my Windows server hosted on AWS. The server sits behind a proxy which directs traffic to the internet.

From my account, I can `pip install` any packages, and it works fine if I set my proxy on `inetcpl.cpl`. I can also run the python script without any issues.

However i have a user on the same server (let's call him john doe), when he tries to `pip install` a package, he gets the error message `Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS`. We found a way around this to use `pip install --proxy` but when he runs the python script, he gets the error `SSLError Max retries exceeded with url [SSL: Wrong Version Number]`. He also has the proxy setup in `inetcpl.cpl`

I want him to be able to run the script and the `pip` commands without the `--proxy` or without having to continuously set `http_proxy` variables like I am able to run the script just fine.

Can someone help out as to why we are getting this SSL error even though he has proxy setup on his user profile ?

Comment: I think you try with tls 1.0 or ssl1/2/3, this can be adjusted in the same dialog afaik

Comment: This error has usually nothing to do with an actual wrong TLS version. Instead the https_proxy is likely set to `https://ip:port` whereas it should only be `http://ip:port` - i.e. the proxy itself is not accessed by https but by plain http (https tunneling over the proxy is still secure). In this case the non-TLS error reply of the proxy gets interpreted as TLS which is bogus and leads to misleading errors like wrong version number.

Comment: @steffen then why does it work when i log in with my account? Is there anything that is different across accounts for proxies?

Comment: @MervinHemaraju:  Different users can have different environment variables, thus also different proxy settings for pip.

Comment: Where can i check those proxy settings for pip?

Answer (score -1):

Add the python-argument  --ignoressl. Then it works!
"E:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe" "E:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\tools\admin\manageservice.py" -u  -p  --ignoressl -s http://localhost:6080/arcgis/admin -n  -o stop